# Right way to go about bipolar power supply?

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator

I need a reasonably steady power supply that provides +12V, -12V and ground for an audio application. I haven't found many resources online for how do design this type of circuit. This is what I came up with. Are there any major problems? Is it ok to use a voltage divider in this way? My power supply can supply up to 50V if needed, so that's not a concern. Thanks.[image]

Comment: How much current you need? What kind of power supply you have that provides the 32 to 50 V?

Comment: The 7812 won't be able to regulate your negative voltage. You need a regulator made for negative voltages. Moreover, please simulate it and load just one rail to ground. Watch what happens to the other.

Comment: Just look at this [diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGEqB.png). See where the current must go ***into*** the bottom regulator? It's not going to work. Not even close. There's no way the 100 k resistor will be of any good with over 1 A, either.

Comment: let's cut to the chase. You can't do it with a single input supply. You do need two separate supplies of about 15V each, which can be combined to give +/-15V unregulated.

Comment: If your goal is to start with relatively high voltage DC and get a lower voltage bipolar output then a switching regulator probably makes the most sense. Otherwise if you have access to AC, just buy a bipolar power supply.

Answer (score 3):

Aside from the wrong regulator hacktastical points out:

That won't be good enough, the point you labeled 0V will almost exclusively defined by which, positive or negative voltage rail, draws more current, and even if that wasn't the case, you'd need the current that flows or if the positive-side regulator to go through from the ground to the input of the negative regulator, which it's probably not designed to do.

Also, this will end in smoke if you connect the ground to, for example the chassis, and your 32 V supply is not an isolated one.

You're doing this because a single-ended audio solution wasn't feasible, I assume. You should probably buy a bipolar supply instead of what you're doing now, if that's the case, because you'll want your ground to actually be tied to the midpoint of the thing supplying you current.

In many cases, a single-ended solution is easier, as you can almost generally AC-couple audio signals. Your regulators don't do high currents and thus, powers. Chances are replacing whatever you want to supply with this by a design that works with single-ended supplies is easier and cheaper.

Comment: Help me understand why for example if +12V draws more current, ground would be off. The voltage regulators are capable of holding a steady 12V across a range of different currents, no?

Comment: No, not really. The regulators you chose are bad at regulating if the output voltage is higher than it should; you would need a pretty beefy constant load for this to be reliable. And audio loads aren't constant. And if these regulators weren't bad at correcting towards lower absolute output voltage, you would stand a chance of building an oscillator, where one regulator overshoots a bit, the other tries to correct that...

Comment: these regulator, given input of about 14V or more coming in, will maintain the output at +12V. They DO need a 0V reference on BOTH sides. The ground terminal is used as the reference for BOTH input and output sides. You are not giving a reference on the input side, so the whole 3 rail system (on the output side) will drift around unpredictably with respect to the input voltage. Think of a 3 terminal regulator as 4 terminals, where it so happens that the input reference is joined to the output reference (that is what is really happening).

Answer (score 2):

The power supply needs a center-tap ground return if there is significant single-ended current flowing (that is, you need +/-16V). Otherwise you could make do with regulating just one rail (to 24V) and creating an artificial midpoint virtual ground with an op-amp.

The -12V regulator would need to be negative type, e.g., MC7**9**12CTG, (assuming you have a midpoint return).

The voltage divider isn't really doing anything for you, unless you use it as a reference for a virtual ground.

Answer (score 2):

An unregulated power supply, as simple as this, would do for an audio amplifier.

[image]